# vue.js Cannot read property 'name' of null,but console can't provide the wrong file path

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Many identical error messages appear on the console：

```
 vue.min.js?bust=1541470192660:503 TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
    at normalizeLocation (vue-router.js?bust=1541470192660:1282)
    at VueRouter.resolve (vue-router.js?bust=1541470192660:2580)
    at o.render (vue-router.js?bust=1541470192660:415)
    at o.pn._render (vue.min.js?bust=1541470192660:1334)
    at o.St.before (vue.min.js?bust=1541470192660:2436)
    at St.get (vue.min.js?bust=1541470192660:734)
    at St.getAndInvoke (vue.min.js?bust=1541470192660:769)
    at St.run (vue.min.js?bust=1541470192660:767)
    at At (vue.min.js?bust=1541470192660:701)
    at Array.<anonymous> (vue.min.js?bust=1541470192660:535)
```

I know the cause of the error but I don't know where the error occurred. Can I output the path of the error ? Add Some statements ？

```
function He(e, t, n) {
        if (!B && !U || "undefined" == typeof console) throw e;
        console.error(e)
        //can i output the path about e
    }
```

Comment: How many places in your code do you refer to a property called '.name'?

Comment: Same here. No "name" attribute in my app.